# LibCurl WriteCallback (Async?) - C++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am successfully making an http POST call using the following code:

```
std::string curlString;
CURL* pCurl = curl_easy_init();

if(!pCurl)
    return NULL;

string outgoingUrl = Url;
string postFields = fields;

curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);

curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, outgoingUrl.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postFields.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)postFields.size());

curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &curlString);

curl_easy_perform(pCurl);

curl_easy_cleanup(pCurl);
```

The write callback has the following prototype:

```
size_t CurlWriteCallback(char* a_ptr, size_t a_size, size_t a_nmemb, void* a_userp);
```

Is there a way to do this asynchronously? Currently it waits for the callback to finish before curl_easy_perform returns. This blocking method won't work for a server with many users.

Comment: Did you come to solve this? Can you add your solution to the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [libcurl easy](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html) documentation:

> When all is setup, you tell libcurl to perform the transfer using curl_easy_perform(3). It will then do the entire operation and won't return until it is done (successfully or not).

From the [libcurl multi interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) docs, one of the features as opposed to the "easy" interface:

> 1. Enable multiple simultaneous transfers in the same thread without making it complicated for the application.

Sounds like you want to use the "multi" approach.

Comment: An example of using the multi interface in C++ can be found at http://www.godpatterns.com/2011/09/asynchronous-non-blocking-curl-multi.html